# Overstaying visa in Vietnam by 5(!) minutes

Tags: visas, overstaying, vietnam, ho-chi-minh-city

I am in a situation where I landed in Vietnam, and found out I only get 15 days of visa by default. I landed 730am Jan 24th and leaves 00:05am on Feb 9th, which by hours is within 15 days, but if you count days it's officially 16 days.

This leaves me with a couple of options as far as I understand.

- Buy a new ticket home the day before. Price: 7-800 USD.
- Doing a 1-day-trip to somewhere else while being here. Price: 100-150 USD but very inconvenient
- Get a visa extension. I think it requires my passport and I will travel locally and not stay for many days in same place - not sure it's an option.
- Pay some fine in airport - as I could read it's between 500k VND and 2 million VND.

Is there any thoughts? What is the desired option here? On paper the fine at airport seems best, but I am worried of some downside I don't see.

For any note, I am leaving from Ho Chi Minh to Copenhagen.

Comment: Seems like you'll be going through the outgoing immigration checks well before midnight-- so *maybe* it's not a problem.

Comment: I don't see how it is within 15 days by hours. In my book between 2016-01-24 07:30:00 and 2016-02-09 00:05:00 you have 376.58 = 15*24+16.58 hours. In days it would be 17 days: 8 in January and 9 in February, of which you can remove one because you will pass immigration before midnight.

Comment: Relevant: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46070/how-close-to-the-end-of-my-vietnam-tourist-visa-can-i-still-get-an-extension-th?rq=1

Comment: @Lars how did you end up solving the issue?

Comment: @JonathanReez Extended my visa in Da Nang. Costed me 70 USD and took 1 day :-) I am pretty sure you can just take the fine, but there is cases where you are sent back to the city to "fix it". So I didn't take the chance

Comment: And obviously @ptityeti was correct - it was actually 16 days and 5 minutes :-)

Comment: Could you post this comment as an answer, so that the question can be closed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Extended my visa in Da Nang. Costed me 70 USD and took 1 day :-) I am pretty sure you can just take the fine, but there is cases where you are sent back to the city to "fix it". So I didn't take the chance.

And obviously @ptityeti was correct - it was actually 16 days and 5 minutes :-)